# Linux SNMP logger software

Tags: linux, logging, snmpwalk

I have an application running on an old version of Linux using snmpwalk to read data from an instrument. I am experiencing some problems with this instrument. Every once in a while I seem to get a bogus value for an OID, e.g. an alarm can suddenly be triggered for no reason.

I would like to analyze this with another software to determine what is causing this problem (software or equipment). I want to find out if I am having a problem with the snmpwalk Linux command.

Does anyone know of any Linux SNMP software to log the traffic?
Basically, I want to double check that snmpwalk is working properly.

I have really tried searching the internet for such a software but I haven't found anyone so far.

Comment: I would say that it is more likely that your instrument is reporting false values rather than `snmpwalk` being defective.

Comment: I agree with you Oliver Salzburg. I get the same result when I am using the agent++ C++ class. I need to verify this so I can prove this to the manufacturer that doesn't seem to do anything about the problems.

Comment: I only know of software like Nagios and Cacti which aid in graphing SNMP data, but, internally, those rely on `snmpwalk`, so that won't help you, I guess.

Comment: I am using this command to talk to the instrument: "snmpwalk -v 1 -c public 192.168.100.167 .1.3.6.1.4.1.3442.2" The status I receive look something like this: "SNMPv2-SMI::enterprise.3442.2.1.2.0 = INTEGER: 10"  Is this a version 1 or version 2 instrument? Is my command correct?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the instrument it self.
We have received a firmware update to fix this problem.